# Using true north bearing in label expression

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, atlas, north-arrow

In QGIS there is an option to rotate the north arrow as grid north or true north. For my case I need the true north angle. The rotation works just fine but now I also wanted to add the image rotation of said north arrow as a text label. Now I wondered if I can query the value which is actually displayed inside the item properties of the north arrow.

[image]

Up to now I tried grabbing it using `item_variables('northarrow')` with no success. Furthermore I tried using a python function in the label expression utilizing `bearingTrueNorth()` which looks as following:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *


@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')

def truenorth(value1,feature,parent):

 crs=QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326)
 transformContext=QgsCoordinateTransformContext()

 bearing=bearingTrueNorth(crs,transformContext, QgsPointXY(value1))

return bearing
```

I tried various iterations but to no avail. My `value1` is as QgsGeometry grabbed by using `centroid(@atlas_geometry)`.

Is there any known solution to this?